# Claim based security with MVC custom login page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wif, claims-based-identity

I am developing MVC application and want to use WIF & Claim based security.
However I am very disappointed with the way login is perfomed. I mean redirection to STS login page and then redirecting back to my page. That is not user-friendly at all.

I want to implement login page in my application (it fact it will be popup dialog). Than using Web API I want to be able to perform STS request and get security token and initialize WIF infrastructure (Principle etc).

Is it a good way to go with?
Did anybody do something similar?
Does anybody have some samples of what I am trying to do?

I just worry that I don't have control over the STS login page layout & style.
Also I will have mobile application and must perform login using Web API service.

What can you advice?
Thanks

Comment: Please, stop referring to "ASP.NET MVC" simply as "MVC". One is a framework, while other is a language-independent design pattern. It's like calling IE - "the internet"

Comment: http://chris.59north.com/post/2013/04/09/Building-a-simple-custom-STS-using-VS2012-ASPNET-MVC.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Well - you can do that of course. This does not need to be WIF specific. Call a service, pass credentials - and when OK set the login cookie.

But if you want SSO you have to make a user agent roundtrip to the STS - otherwise you cannot establish a logon session.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [MembershipReboot](https://github.com/brockallen/BrockAllen.MembershipReboot) membership provider which uses claims-based security and is not based on microsoft's traditional membership provider.

It does not have a documentation, but in the zip file you can find 2 sample projects that uses MemebershipReboot provider, which explains all you need to know about it.

In fact after reading this [blog post](http://brockallen.com/2012/09/02/think-twice-about-using-membershipprovider-and-simplemembership) today, I decided to use this approach in my current project. I'm still struggling with it now and I'm so excited !

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Ashkan's recommendation [Brock Allen](http://brockallen.com/) provides solid documentation about how to implement [MembershipReboot](https://github.com/brockallen/BrockAllen.MembershipReboot) in association with IdentityServer. You can find that their is a way to configure a custom implementation Here. Also their are a few tutorials on vimeo from Dominick Baier (leastprivilege) that will provide a full walk through on getting started! I hope this helps!